# Gajim SASL External client authentication

Tags: xmpp, pkcs#12, sasl

Ok , this is a little off . I have a XMPP sever that supports XEP-00178 (SASL-External)(namely : openfire)  and I am using Gajim client to test it. Now I created a .p12 file(using openssl)  for the registered user on the server with the common name equal to the user name. The .p12 file is encrypted. But when I use the Gajim to add the user's corresponding encrypted .p12 file , it prompts for the pass phrase , which I supply correctly but it just fails with the error :

Unknown error while loading certificate from file /root/sslCA/alice.p12

I tried opening the same alice.p12 using OpenSSL and everything works just great. Would it be wise to remove the password from the .p12 file? or Is there something that I am doing wrong with regards to Gajim?

Comment: Ok solved this. This is because of the pass phrase passed on as a uni-code. Modified the nbxmpp.tls_nb.py .

Comment: have you been able to successfully login using certificates? I am trying to achieve the same. Could you please help?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was on a holiday. Yes I was able to login using certificates. Server used was openfire and client was Gajim and I had a bunch of client certificates that were signed by a CA that openfire trusts. Little modification needs to be done in the source of Gajim (a type cast of unicode into string).

Comment: I am sorry to bother you, Could you please list steps if any you have followed to configure openfire to work with client certificates? I posted in their forum as well. No one responded. I see a few blog posts, but could not successfully create one that works, using those instructions. my email address is srinathreddib at gmail.com

Comment: I will do this today evening (in India) since I am busy right now with a deadline.I do have a wiki page but that's on company's private portal. I cant share that. I will mail you a new wiki or update my blog.

Comment: Hey man , I will get back to you, I am still stuck in the office :(

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate that

Comment: Hello amrx, did you get a chance to upload the instructions to your blog? I do not know if it is the problem with certificate generation or openfire configuration?  Sorry to bug you!!

Comment: Hello amrx, Could you please share your blog post? I am sorry to bother you during busy schedule. It would be really helpful for me, as I am stuck on this for over 2 weeks now.

Comment: Give ur mail, will mail the screen shots of the wiki page , really had no time to write up the steps in  blog.

Comment: I am sorry about your schedule. my email id is srinathreddib@gmail.com